# Github pages with blank page and repo link. Not loading page

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I have googled and searched and cannot find an answer to this.  I have my page at github and it just returns a hyperlink with the readme. Here is the current repo: https://github.com/brianmsantos/brianmsantos.github.io.

[image: brianmsantos.github.io]

Comment: There is an index.html in the public folder

Comment: Your index file must be at the root. For now what you see is the readme file. See https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index.html and add your content there. See https://pages.github.com/

Comment: There is an index.html in the public folder

Comment: But its not on the root of your repo. How's github.io supposed to know that your index.html file lives in the public folder?

Comment: Thanks Graham, I was unsure why, I had an idea it might need to be in the root. I guess the other ways I have built apps I used a builder like webpack to build and get the index.html file from the folders.

Answer (score -1):

1 create package.json and add

```
{
  "homepage": "https://name.github.io/appname",
  …
}
```

2.Use the terminal and install gh pages using command:
 npm install --save gh-pages

3.Add this to your scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
      "predeploy": "npm run build",
      "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
      …
  }
```

4. make deploy using npm run deploy in commandline
   5 in your repository settings set the branch to gh-pages branch and save